# Apama To Mongo DB Connectivity

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, apama

I want to connect to Mongo DB from Apama and store the events there in JSON document format. Is there any way to establish the connectivity either using JDBC or Java API invocation?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently (up to Apama 10.3.1) no built-in connectivity for MongoDB.
However, I expect you should be able to use one of our standard public extension API's to add such an extension.  Most likely would be to use the Correlator "[Connectivity Plugin](http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.1.1/apama_10.3.1.1_webhelp/apama-webhelp/#page/apama-webhelp%2Fco-ConApaAppToExtCom_working_with_connectivity_plug_ins.html%23)" API with a 3rd-party client library in either C++ or Java.

Kev